# from header in PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

Im using PHPMailer to send emails. Now I have a contact form and when a user fills it out I should receive an email. In the email, when I click reply I'd like to have customer email in there, however im getting my own server email. I also want the email to say 'from: customer@hisemail.com' (customer email).

I believe i have to setup headers here. However I couldn't find any info about PHPMailer headers... Maybe someone could give me an advice? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Sender     = $email;
$mail->From       = 'myemail@myserver.com';
$mail->FromName   = $fullname;
$mail->MsgHTML($question);
$mail->AddAddress($mailmanager, "support");
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $fullname);
if(!$mail->send()) { echo 'mail not sent'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. It will fail to deliver on most ISPs because you are trying to forge the from address. Instead, send from your own address and add the customer's address as a reply-to address:

```
$mail->addReplyTo($customeremail);
```